# Disable com port until login

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, drivers, batch-file

Using Windows 7 (64bit). I have an RFID Pad connected to my PC via USB.

My issue is that whenever the RFID pad is connected and I start the PC, I get a blue screen of death just after the 'Starting Windows' screen.

I have tried to troubleshoot this and I have found the following (after lots of trial and error);

- If I remove the RFID USB from the PC **before startup**, it boots just fine
- If I plugin the RFID USB **after login**, it works fine
- If I disable the RFID port (COM4) in device manager then reboot, it works
- If I enable the RFID port (COM4) in device manager then reboot, I get a blue screen

Presumably somewhere around the Windows OS Loader, the RFID device is being recognized and for whatever reason my PC doesn't like it. However if I 'trick' the PC and plug the device in after login, all is well.

The issue isn't local to one PC, it's several that are setup the same. Presumably it's a driver issue, but I've tried numerous drivers and getting nowhere.

So, is there anyway I can 'delay' the RFID port (COM4) from being active until **after** I login? I'm pretty sure this will work.

I have been looking at MS [devcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707(v=vs.85).aspx) but I'm not sure if it would work, of what sort of .bat script I would require?

I'd need to permanently disable the COM4 port. Enable only after login.

Any help here is appreciated as I'm lost :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use the disable USB port program via Task Scheduler on user logoff and enable on user logon?

Or use Microsoft' [devcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707(v=vs.85).aspx) command to disable/enable the specific device using Task Scheduler.

Comment: Your welcome let me know the results

Comment: I thought this worked but it actually doesn't :( I still receive a BSOD randomly when working at the PC. I've still accepted your answer though. Any other suggestions would be great though! @NetworkKingPin

Comment: Hey I just found [This Link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://superuser.com/questions/14917/disable-usb-drives-during-boot-up&ved=0ahUKEwjl8LL367PLAhWMez4KHeMsA44QFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNEEMZGllgpgGkJR1yliroMvdmi-fQ&sig2=92PBEoTXYnPC8L-R2hCcww) which may actually help you out with your issue.

Comment: And sorry it didn't help much before.  I hope this helps if it does I will add it in and note the credit.