# how to prevent Linux boot on a windows 8 laptop

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, bios

I have a Toshiba Satellite L55-A5284 laptop with a Windows 8.1 home edition installed.
I would like to configure it in a such a manner which would prevent one from loading/installing Linux from a USB drive.
I do have UEFI secure boot enabled, however, I am still able to load Linux Mint from a USB drive.
What other steps can I take to 'seal off' this Windows machine?

Thank you

Comment: You accepted an answer, so it's great that your own needs were satisfied.  However, the site is a knowledge base, with a purpose of helping others with similar problems.  Your question is pretty ambiguous about the degree and type of protection requested.  Is this just so that you don't accidentally install Linux yourself, so you need some hoops to jump through?  Is this in a shared environment, and you want to prevent a knowledgeable person from changing your machine?  How knowledgeable and committed a person do you need to prevent from changing your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add admin and system password
2. Choose only HDD as the bootable media remove usb and other options or move them after HDD if no option to remove

Referring 
[Disable USB drives during boot up?](https://superuser.com/questions/14917/disable-usb-drives-during-boot-up)

Now with this setting nobody can boot from other media except your HDD even that with your password

Comment: please elaborate: when you said 'lock... power on' with a password, how does one accomplish locking a 'power on' in Windows? when you wrote 'lock BIOS', did you mean with admin password or with system password? thanks

Comment: You should see system and bios password enable those and then disable usb boot can't elaborate further every bios is unique so you will have to look for those options

Comment: Feel free to update the answer with actual locations so it will help others

Comment: Also attach screenshots of bios if settings are not clear

Comment: Yes I meant admin and system password

Comment: I understand that BIOS settings can be quite different depending on the manufacturer. please elaborate what you meant by 'power on' so that I would know what to look for. I will try posting screen shots when I am done with this. thanks!

Comment: Password for power on I mean the one if enabled you would get a prompt to enter password every time you start computer without that nobody can access

Comment: thanks again. is there anything that can be done on the OS (Windows in this case) or BIOS firmware level? I am asking because one can perform a BIOS reset.

Comment: I mean if they can open it up to reset your bios then they can just take your hard drive and copy data to prevent that you should look into hard drive encryption

Comment: Personally I don't let anybody else touch my personal laptop if physical hacking is also a concern then you should look into hard drive encryption